# Using a dollar sign in enum (pypeg)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypeg

I want to match types of the form either `$f`, `$c`, ..., `$d` using [pypeg](https://fdik.org/pyPEG/), so I tried putting it in an `Enum` as follows:

```
class StatementType(Keyword):
    grammar = Enum( K("$f"), K("$c"), 
                    K("$v"), K("$e"),
                    K("$a"), K("$p"),
                    K("$d"))
```

However, this fails:

```
>>> k = parse("$d", StatementType)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pypeg2/__init__.py", line 667, in parse
    t, r = parser.parse(text, thing)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pypeg2/__init__.py", line 794, in parse
    raise r
  File "<string>", line 1
    $d
    ^
SyntaxError: expecting StatementType
```

I have also tried replacing the `$x` with `\$x` to escape the `$` character. I also tried prepending `r"\$x"` in hopes that it treats it as a regex object. Neither of these combinations seem to work and give the same error message. How do I get it to match the example I gave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [default regex for Keywords](https://fdik.org/pyPEG/grammar_elements.html#keyword) is `\w+`. You can change it by setting the `Keyword.regex` class variable:

```
class StatementType(Keyword):
    grammar = Enum( K("$f"), K("$c"),
                    K("$v"), K("$e"),
                    K("$a"), K("$p"),
                    K("$d"))

Keyword.regex = re.compile(r"\$\w") # e.g. $a, $2, $_
k = parse("$d", StatementType)
```